# How to allow only numeric input, allow 2 digits after decimal and allow to input minus in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'd like to restrict users input in a form to a decimal with a maximum of two numbers after (.) And users allow to input minus. and a text field which only accepts a number.

```
<input type="text" name="debet[]" placeholder="debet" class=" money" value="0"/>
```

Script:

```
$('body').on('focus',".money", function(){
        $(this).simpleMoneyFormat();
    });
```

[Here is a jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tL2s8g7n/)

Somebody can help me with this?

Comment: `<input type="number" step="0.01" />`

Comment: Try having a look at this JS library: http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" name="debet[]" placeholder="debet" class="money"/> 
var timer;

$('input').keyup(function (){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function (event) {
        $('input').val(Number($('input').val()).toFixed(2))
    }, 1000);
});
```

this should do, it will fire the event every 1 seconds

https://jsfiddle.net/usdf1nx6/

Comment: thanks for answere, but automatic Number formatting not working. i also need  Number formatting such as : XXX,XXX.XX

Comment: Like I had suggested to you via the edit (added regex tag), this is more of a regex question, bro. Try reading about regexes

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener for `blur` event on input. And, then use a regex to validate the input using [**`RegExp.test()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method

```
let input = document.querySelector('input'); // input element
const checkRegex = /^\-?\d[\,\d]+\d\.\d{0,2}$/; // regex for the format: DDD,DDD.DD

input.addEventListener('blur', evt => {
  if(checkRegex.test(input.value)) {
    input.style.borderColor = '#080'; // indicates correct input
  } else {
    input.style.borderColor = '#F46'; // indicates wrong input
  }
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/Rahul_V7/pen/KrVYGq)

Comment: thanks for answer, but your demo not working for me.

Comment: @SigitPrasetya can you explain what is not working for you?